# Open File in Directory from Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, download

I am working on a file management application which parses excel files from the business and uploads the latest data to the database. Is it possible to link back to that file from the webpage so that when they open it to make changes they can save it without having to look up the path to that file?

For example, if i upload the file "C:\some\nested\directory\file.xlsx", is there a way to open the file from online so that when I click "Save" in Excel it will pull up that path by default?

This is the code I have to open the file, which works, just without the correct path since it is downloading it as a tempororary file.

```
[HttpGet]
public FileStreamResult ViewFile(int id)
{
    var report = _reportRepository.GetById(id);
    var file = System.IO.File.Open(report.FilePath, FileMode.Open);

    return File(file, "application/vnd-ms-excel", report.FileName);
}
```

Comment: What you have to do is to write a plugin for Excel that can listen to the save command and post the file back to the website.

Comment: Is this also true if it is an internal application and the file is saved on a shared drive? (I don't think a plug-in is within scope of the project).

Comment: Please don't add "C# .NET" to your titles like that. That's what tags are for.

Comment: If you return a FileStream like you do in your example, your clients will most probably create a new file in their temp or download folder. What you could test instead is to return a RedirectResult pointing to `\\share\files\file.xls`. That should open the actual file from its actual location.
You probably need something like a Windows Service that monitors the folder containing the files, so that they can be processed once they are saved.

Comment: If it's from a shared drive, then one solution would be to have the web page return a link to that path (so that Excel opens the file from the shared drive instead of retrieving from the web page). A bit messy, but other than @Adam Tuliper's WebDAV solution it's about your only option (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Also, if there's a possibility that multiple users could be editing the file at the same time, storing it on a shared drive is asking for race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but not the way you are trying to.

The server needs WebDAV support to be able to do this.
Here is an example of download.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10241992/downloading-file-from-webdav-with-c.aspx

MS talks about it a bit here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397370%28v=office.12%29.aspx

https://serverfault.com/questions/52626/excel-file-always-opens-in-read-only-mode-over-webdav